# How to collect disk read/write activity over a given period of time?

Tags: linux, disk-usage, io

Sometimes, especially upon login, I have a lot of disk activity. I can use `iotop` to see what's doing that at a given moment, but I would like to have an integral table over a given time, say the first 5 minutes after I run it.

I'm interested in the percentage breakdown of the disk activity each program was using over the 5 minutes in total.

Is there a tool or a simple script I can run for that cause?

Comment: `iotop -a`?​​​​

Answer (score 5):

You can use `iotop -b` (batch mode) inside of a loop based on # of seconds.

That will spit out everything and then redirect it to a file.

I'm trying to find a shell loop example to do that but i don't do shell programming much.

If i started the command by hand, i would run:
`iotop -botqk > ~/log-iotop.txt` or something similar.

Comment: Output to a file is handy, but I only need the "last screen" of the `iotop -a` cummulative output, as @StéphaneChazelas suggested.

Comment: I think `iotop -abtqk` might be what you're looking for -- it will output everything for you with timestamps and when 5 minutes are up, press Ctrl C and it will stop.  Then you have everything of the last 5 minutes on your screen that you can scroll through.

Comment: using `-abtqk` produces duplicates in the ouput and a very large file. it is kinda useful though.